# Python ipywidgets: Setting different colors for Button

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

The [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#Button) explains the basic colors you can set on the button.

```
widgets.Button(
    description='Click me',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='check'
)
```

Are there additional colors that can be used? How?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation explains that widgets have a [style attribute](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute) that has different properties depending on the widget type.

In our case

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
b=widgets.Button(description=button_style, button_style='')
b.style.keys

['_model_module',
 '_model_module_version',
 '_model_name',
 '_view_count',
 '_view_module',
 '_view_module_version',
 '_view_name',
 'button_color',
 'font_weight']
```

So, apart from the basic colors

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
for button_style in ['primary','success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' , '']:
  print(button_style)
  widgets.Button(description=button_style, button_style=button_style)
```

[image]

You can have any of the [html colors](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-names/)

```
name_colors="GreenYellow Chartreuse LawnGreen Lime LimeGreen".split() 
for button_color in name_colors:
  print(button_color)
  b=widgets.Button(description=button_style, button_style='')
  b.style.button_color = button_color
  b
```

[image]

---

This may be needed in your case to display multiple outputs

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```